# calculus on manifolds (spivak) problem 2-41 (c)

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

> 2-41. let $f:\Bbb{R} \times \Bbb{R} \rightarrow \Bbb{R}$ be differentiable. for each $x \in \Bbb{R}$ define $g_x: \Bbb{R} \rightarrow \Bbb{R}$ by $g_x(y)=f(x,y)$. suppose that for each $x$ there is a unique $y$ with $g'_x(y)=0$; let $c(x)$ be this $y$.
>
> (a) If $D_{2,2}f(x,y) \neq 0$ for all $(x,y)$, show that $c$ is differentiable and $c'(x)=-\frac{D_{2,1}f(x,c(x))}{D_{2,2}f(x,c(x))}$.
>
> Hint: $g'_x(y)=0$ can be written $D_2f(x,y)=0$.
>
> (b) show that if $c'(x)=0$, then for some $y$ we have
>
> $D_{2,1}f(x,y)=0$
>
> $D_2f(x,y)=0$
>
> (c) let $f(x,y)=x(y \,log \,y \,- \,y)- y \,log\, x$. find $\underset{\frac{1}{2}\leq x \leq 2}{max}(\underset {\frac{1}{2}\leq y \leq 1}{min}f(x,y))$.

for the given $f(x,y)$, $c(x)=e^{log\,x/x}. \, c'(x)=0 \implies x=1$ and since $c(1)=1,$ according to part (b), $D_{2,2}f(1,1)=0$ and $D_2f(1,1)=0$

But how do I know $\underset{\frac{1}{2}\leq x \leq 2}{max}(\underset {\frac{1}{2}\leq y \leq 1}{min}f(x,y))$ occurrs at $(1,1)$? What other critical points do I have to look at?

please give a hint.please **do not** provide solution.

Comment: [Welcome to Math.SE!](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4928/290189) Please use MathJax and see [MathJax tutorial](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/290189). Please [don't use pictures for critical portions](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/20529/290189) of your post. Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched and are not viewable to those who use screen readers.  Please read [this post](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9960/290189)for information on writing a good question. People will be more willing to help if you [edit] your question to include an explanation of your own attempts.

Comment: @GNUSupporter 8964 thanks for the comments regarding picture. necessary edits are made. but I sincerely disagree with your suggestion "to include an explanation of your own attempts." I have stated as well as explained my attempts

Comment: I apologize for the quoted remark.  I should have copied a better template.  Close and down votes withdrawn thanks to your edit.  I seize this chance to introduce you [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/), a math search engine by typing LaTeX code. It will help you find other math posts from the TeX code, except those containing text images. Btw, please [don't use `\frac` in exponents or limits of integrals](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5057/290189). It looks bad and confusing, and it rarely appears in professional mathematics typesetting.